# Edit Action not work in Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am Created one custom module but Edit Action Can not work ?

Here is my `Controller`

```
public function editAction()
    {
        echo "Harshil";
       $manageoutofstockId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        var_dump ($manageoutofstockId);
        $manageoutofstockModel  = Mage::getModel('manageoutofstock/manageoutofstock')->load($manageoutofstockId);
        var_dump ($manageoutofstockId);
        if ($manageoutofstockModel->getId() || $manageoutofstockId == 0) {

            Mage::register('manageoutofstock_data', $manageoutofstockModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('manageoutofstock/items');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('manageoutofstock/adminhtml_manageoutofstock_edit'))
                 ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('manageoutofstock/adminhtml_manageoutofstock_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

And here is my `Form.php`

```
<?php
class Vrinsoft_Manageoutofstock_Block_Adminhtml_Manageoutofstock_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('manageoutofstock_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Item information')));

    $fieldset->addField('product_id', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Product Id'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'product_id',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'label' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Email ID'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Email ID'),
        //'style' => 'width:98%; height:400px;',
        'wysiwyg' => false,
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Status'),
        'name' => 'status',
        'values' => array(
            array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Active'),
            ),
            array(
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => Mage::helper('manageoutofstock')->__('Inactive'),
            ),
        ),
    ));




 if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getManageoutofstockData() )
{
$form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getManageoutofstockData());
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setManageoutofstockData(null);
} elseif ( Mage::registry('manageoutofstock_data') ) {
$form->setValues(Mage::registry('manageoutofstock_data')->getData());
} 
return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
```

Can any one help me ? Any kind of help will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Change `return parent::_prepareForm();` to `return $this;` in Form.php